# C: how to store integers by reading line by line with a random layout?

Tags: c, line, fgets, scanf

I need to read a file and store each number (int) in a variable, when it sees \n or a "-" (the minus sign means that it should store the numbers from 1 to 5 (1-5)) it needs to store it into the next variable. How should I proceed?

I was thinking of using fgets() but I can't find a way to do what I want.

The input looks like this:

```
0
0
5 10
4
2 4
5-10 2 3 4 6 7-9
4 3
```

These are x y positions.

Comment: Show us some code which you tried and people will help you with it.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `fscanf` to read one `int` at a time, and when it's negative, it is obviously the second part of a range. Or is `-4--2` a valid input?

Comment: All the integers have to be positive. Every line has it's signification so I was thinking to do a fgets and store each line separately and then afterward parse them through a sscanf in order to just keep the useful bits.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Go ahead, try it, and if you run into specific problems, post your code.